# How to arrange the first and second pages in php?

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php
function paginate($reload, $page, $tpages) {
    $adjacents = 2;
    $prevlabel = "&lsaquo; Prev";
    $nextlabel = "Next &rsaquo;";
    $out = "";
    if ($page == 1) { 
        $out.= "<span style=\"display:none;\">" . $prevlabel . "</span>\n";
    } elseif ($page == 2) {
        $out.= "<li><a  href=\"" . $reload . "\">" . $prevlabel . "</a>\n</li>";
    } else {
        $out.= "<li><a  href=\"" . $reload . "&amp;page=" . ($page - 1) . "\">" . $prevlabel . "</a>\n</li>";
    }

    $pmin = ($page > $adjacents) ? ($page - $adjacents) : 1;
    $pmax = ($page < ($tpages - $adjacents)) ? ($page + $adjacents) : $tpages;
    for ($i = $pmin; $i <= $pmax; $i++) {
        if ($i == $page) {
            $out.= "<li><a href='' class=\"active\">" . $i . "</a></li>\n";
        } elseif ($i == 1) {
            $out.= "<li><a  href=\"" . $reload . "\">" . $i . "</a>\n</li>";
        } else {
            $out.= "<li><a  href=\"" . $reload . "&amp;page=" . $i . "\">" . $i . "</a>\n</li>";
        }
    }
    if ($page < $tpages) {
        $out.= "<li><a  href=\"" . $reload . "&amp;page=" . ($page + 1) . "\">" . $nextlabel . "</a>\n</li>";
    } else {
        $out.= "<span style='font-size:11px'>" . $nextlabel . "</span>\n";
    }
    $out.= "";
    return $out;
}
?>
```

How to when the first page , appears 5 points. For E.g, When I was at page **1** , then I would like this **1** 2 3 4 5.. but if I change the `"$ adjacents=2;"` to 4. Indeed, when the 1 page there is a 1 2 3 4 5.. But when I moved to the page=7 , then , The page displayed 1 2 3 4 5 6 **7** 8 9  a lot of numbers, or when I moved to page=12. The page displayed 8 9 10 11 **12** 13 14 15 16.. Whereas , I Want to display 5 digits only.

How so that when the first and second page only, is made to appear 5 digit page ?And when I turn the page , eg page **12** like this. 10 11 **12** 13 14.

or when in page **1** to be like this **1** 2 3 4 5

or when in page **2** to be like this 1 **2** 3 4 5

or when in page **3** to be like this 1 2 **3** 4 5.. etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste this script

```
<?php
function paginate($reload, $page, $tpages) {
    $adjacents = 2;
    $prevlabel = "&lsaquo; Prev";
    $nextlabel = "Next &rsaquo;";
    $out = "";
    if ($page == 1) { 
        $out.= "<span style=\"display:none;\">" . $prevlabel . "</span>\n";    $pmin = ($page > $adjacents) ? ($page - $adjacents) : 1;

    $adjacents = 4;


    $pmax = ($page < ($tpages - $adjacents)) ? ($page + $adjacents) : $tpages;
    for ($i = $pmin; $i <= $pmax; $i++) {
        if ($i == $page) {
            $out.= "<li><a href='' class=\"active\">" . $i . "</a></li>\n";
        } elseif ($i == 1) {
            $out.= "<li><a  href=\"" . $reload . "\">" . $i . "</a>\n</li>";
        } else {
            $out.= "<li><a  href=\"" . $reload . "&amp;page=" . $i . "\">" . $i . "</a>\n</li>";
        }
    }
    if ($page < $tpages) {
        $out.= "<li><a  href=\"" . $reload . "&amp;page=" . ($page + 1) . "\">" . $nextlabel . "</a>\n</li>";
    } else {
        $out.= "<span style='font-size:11px'>" . $nextlabel . "</span>\n";
    }
    $out.= "";
    return $out;
    } elseif ($page == 2) {
        $out.= "<li><a  href=\"" . $reload . "\">" . $prevlabel . "</a>\n</li>";
    $adjacents = 3;
    $pmin = ($page > $adjacents) ? ($page - $adjacents) : 1;
    $pmax = ($page < ($tpages - $adjacents)) ? ($page + $adjacents) : $tpages;
    for ($i = $pmin; $i <= $pmax; $i++) {
        if ($i == $page) {
            $out.= "<li><a href='' class=\"active\">" . $i . "</a></li>\n";
        } elseif ($i == 1) {
            $out.= "<li><a  href=\"" . $reload . "\">" . $i . "</a>\n</li>";
        } else {
            $out.= "<li><a  href=\"" . $reload . "&amp;page=" . $i . "\">" . $i . "</a>\n</li>";
        }
    }
    if ($page < $tpages) {
        $out.= "<li><a  href=\"" . $reload . "&amp;page=" . ($page + 1) . "\">" . $nextlabel . "</a>\n</li>";
    } else {
        $out.= "<span style='font-size:11px'>" . $nextlabel . "</span>\n";
    }
    $out.= "";
    return $out;
    } else {
        $out.= "<li><a  href=\"" . $reload . "&amp;page=" . ($page - 1) . "\">" . $prevlabel . "</a>\n</li>";

    $pmin = ($page > $adjacents) ? ($page - $adjacents) : 1;
    $pmax = ($page < ($tpages - $adjacents)) ? ($page + $adjacents) : $tpages;
    for ($i = $pmin; $i <= $pmax; $i++) {
        if ($i == $page) {
            $out.= "<li><a href='' class=\"active\">" . $i . "</a></li>\n";
        } elseif ($i == 1) {
            $out.= "<li><a  href=\"" . $reload . "\">" . $i . "</a>\n</li>";
        } else {
            $out.= "<li><a  href=\"" . $reload . "&amp;page=" . $i . "\">" . $i . "</a>\n</li>";
        }
    }
    if ($page < $tpages) {
        $out.= "<li><a  href=\"" . $reload . "&amp;page=" . ($page + 1) . "\">" . $nextlabel . "</a>\n</li>";
    } else {
        $out.= "<span style='font-size:11px'>" . $nextlabel . "</span>\n";
    }
    $out.= "";
    return $out;
    }
}
?>
```